# Namespace handling with SAX in Java

Tags: java, xml-namespaces, saxparser

Consider the following input xml document:

```
<oracle:EMP xmlns:oracle="http://www.oracle.com/xml"/>
```

...and the following handler:

```
final class XMLizatorSaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(uri + "," + localName + "," + qName);
    }
}
```

When using it with a `SAXParser` I would expect the following outupt:

```
uri: http://www.oracle.com/xml
localName: EMP
qName: oracle:EMP
```

But I get this instead:

```
uri:
localName:
qName: oracle:EMP
```

Why? How can I get correct information?

Comment: Do you have the namespace feature enabled in your parser configuration? You need to set the http://xml.org/sax/features/namespaces in order for namespaces to be guaranteed to be reported.

Comment: How do I check that? is that a SAXParser setting or what?

Comment: Ok found, need to call saxParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true) before  saxParserFactory.newSAXParser().

Answer (score 5):

Ok, thanks to Steve's hint I found the solution.

Need to call `SaxParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);` before `SaxParserFactory.newSAXParser();`

Here is full code:

```
SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
saxParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); // here is the trick

SAXParser parser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();

parser.parse(in, handler);
```

Comment: The fact that SAXParserFactory and DocumentBuilderFactory default to non-namespace-aware parsing always seemed to me like a mistake in the specs, but I guess we're stuck with it now for backwards compatibility reasons.